# Based on a value of a parameter/condition I want to inject a dependency in my class. How can I do that in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have one interface and there are many of its implementation. I have a hashmap which contains rendererId (eg 1,2,3) as key and class name of corresponding renderer implementation. Now in my service class I want to inject the dependent bean based on the Id. Lets say for a request, id is 1 that time in my service class I want to inject implementation1. How it can be done in spring boot(with annotation)? If you can provide pseudo code it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that this will work on a *per request* basis. As by default every component in spring is a singleton.

Comment: By Annotation i am not sure it is possible

Comment: What is the Scope of you service is it Singleton or Request?

Comment: scope is singleton.

Comment: @KrishanuAdhikari you're probably better of creating a `Map<RequestId, YourService>` and then select the specific service by using `Map#get()`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to dynamically change the @Autowire qualifier, so you can use the ApplicationContext

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public void requestMethod(){
   MyServiceImpl1 myServiceImpl1= applicationContext.getBean("id1");
}
```

Comment: Does this mean something like this:
 
<code>
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public Interface getImplementation(HashMap.get(Key)){
   Interface implementation= applicationContext.getBean("classname/value of the corresponding key");
return implementation;
}
</code>